# Conditionally display html based on apex:variable

Tags: visualforce, javascript-controller

I've seen [Conditionally Render HTML in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/conditionally-render-html-in-visualforce) but it seems to handle the checking on the apex side then simply reference that when determining whether to display but I don't think I can do that in my case.

```
<script>
function myMod(num, denom){
    alert(num % denom);
    return (num % denom) == 0;
}
</script>

-- stuff 


<apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!things}" var="thing">
-- stuff --&nbsp;
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="myMod({!rowNum}, 4)" layout="none"> <hr/> </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Basically the problem is that the hr/ isn't displaying

Answer (score 0):

Unlike lightning, you cannot use javascript functions inside the `rendered` tag of a visualforce (you might have noticed that not even the `alert` you have there is called), you will have to put your logic in Salesforce formula style

Try replacing your outputPanel with the following

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!MOD(rowNum, 4) = 0}" layout="none"> <hr/> </apex:outputPanel>
```

For example, 
View

```
<apex:page controller="ExampleController">
    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!things}" var="thing">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!MOD(rowNum, 4) = 0}" layout="none"> <hr/>{!rowNum} {!thing}</apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class ExampleController{

    public List<String> getThings() {
        return new List<String>{'Thing 1','Thing 2','Thing 3','Thing 4', 'Thing 5', 'Thing 6', 'Thing 7', 'Thing 8'};
    }

}
```

It renders

```
 <hr>4 Thing 4 <hr>8 Thing 8
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, it's still not showing up on the page. And yeah I noticed it wasn't calling the alert but thought it might also be because something was wrong with the de-referencing of rowNum or something

Comment: Have you checked that `{!things}` have at least 4 elements? (otherwise it will not show).

Comment: Yeap! I added something to print the number of elements and it went up to like 15

Comment: I'd say that there must be something messing up with it, try to simplify it.

I'll paste a simplified version of view and controller inside my own reply to show a working example

Comment: By the way, apex:variable within an iteration element is not supported. It may or may not work correctly at any given time.